# Is there any way to merge more than 2 videos?

Tags: android, mp4, mp4parser

I need to pragmatically merge/append 6 videos into a single one.

mp4Parser seemed to be a good solution but I have found no way of merging/appending more than 2 videos.

I get always this exception:

```
02-15 14:10:20.113: E/ERRORE(18781): java.io.IOException: 
Cannot merge 
VisualSampleEntry[com.googlecode.mp4parser.boxes.mp4.ESDescriptorBox@0] 
and VisualSampleEntry[com.googlecode.mp4parser.boxes.mp4.ESDescriptorBox@0]
```

Comment: @Sebastian Annies please help Sebastian ! :-))) LISA

Comment: can you please share your code? I need to do a task like this now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Sebastian Annies suggestion,
I have encoded the videos in H264 and now everything works fine!

I can append as many videos as I want.

Comment: Could you please give me a working code for appending more than 2 vidoes?